# jQuery border doesn't change color

Tags: jquery, css

```css
.modal-register-form {
 width: 400px;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 0;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.modal-register-form .user-input {
 width: 70%;
 margin: 25px auto 0;
}

.user-input input {
 font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #8d8d8d;
 padding: 0 16px;
 border: none;
 border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
 border-radius: 3px;
 height: 32px;
}
```

```js
setTimeout(function()
{
    $('.modal-register-form :input[type=text], .modal-register-form :input[type=email], .modal-register-form :input[type=password]').each(function()
    {
        if ($(this).css('border-color') == 'rgb(254, 0, 0)')
        {
            alert('working');
            $(this).css({
                border: '1px solid #e5e5e5'
            });
        }
    });
}, 3250);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know why my code doesn't work? If I click the button, I get the alert "working" but the border doesn't change its color.

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Sandro

Comment: Please provide more information; css and markup...

Comment: I might suggest that relying on something as volatile as border color for your business logic isn't a great idea. What happens when your theme is updated? You now have to update your UI scripting as well.

Comment: Maybe the style property in the css rule is made important

Comment: According to [my tests](https://jsfiddle.net/p4ecqdky/), `border-color` is always empty. It sets `border-top-color`, `left`, etc individually. I don't think it could ever show the alert. Post missing code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
border: '1px solid #e5e5e5'
```

Use this:

```
"border": "1px solid #e5e5e5"
```

Comment: @msg no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *not*  the combined notation, but just the specific single property for `border-color`, and in the following way (quotes around both the property and the value, comma in between):

```
$(this).css({
  "border-color", "#e5e5e5"
});
```

Comment: website is no longer displayed correctly (element is missing).